# C++ function template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Basically I implement my own memory allocation function `Malloc()`, which is

```
void Malloc(size_t size);
```

Now I want to implement my own New and NewArray function, I declare those two functions like this:

```
// template 
  template <class T>
  T* New(void);
  template <class T>
  T* NewArray(unsigned int num);
```

And implementations are:

```
template <class T>
T* MemPool::New<T>()
{
  return (T *)Malloc(sizeof(T));
}

template <class T>
T* MemPool::NewArray<T>(unsigned int num)
{
  if(num < 0)
    return NULL;
  return (T*) Malloc(sizeof(T) * num);
}
```

But compilation fails with this:

```
MP.cpp:482:20: error: function template partial specialization ‘New<T>’ is not allowed
 T* MemPool::New<T>()
                    ^
MP.cpp:488:41: error: function template partial specialization ‘NewArray<T>’ is not allowed
 T* MemPool::NewArray<T>(unsigned int num)
```

Comment: `if(num < 0)` this is impossible.

Comment: ^ Now if someone writes `NewArray(-1)`, `num` will be equal to `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `<T>` here:

```
template <class T>
T* MemPool::New<T>()
//             ^^^
```

Should just be:

```
template <class T>
T* MemPool::New()
```

And the same for `NewArray`.

Comment: Thanks! The compilation passed, but if I use those two functions like this

int *p2 =mp->New<int>();
char *p3 = mp->NewArray<char>(10);

It has another compilation problem:
undefined reference to `int* MemPool::New<int>()'

Comment: @MartinGGWW Because [templates must be defined in the header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/2069064).

Comment: it works after I move them to header file. Thanks for your advice and the link too!